# yiiadmin how to start

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

I am new to YII frame works. I download the yiiadmin from http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiiadmin

But i dont know how to start the admin panel. In the url http://piccy.info/view3/190406/14f153f9643883778f6e1d04774da554/orig/ they show the screen shot.

I installed this in my local server. it supports PHP5.

While opening the Yii admin in browser it just shows the directory listing. Please help to start the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, the extension seems to be quite old and maybe not really what you would expect from an "admin module". It is basically just a front-end to create and edit model instances (db entries). Also, it has never been pushed beyond Beta, so you might not gonna have fun with it, especially if you are a beginner. What you need to make it work:
In your config/main.php add the module to the module array

```
'modules'=>array(

    'yiiadmin' =>array(
            'password'=>'yourpassword',
            'registerModels'=>array(
                //add the models you want to manage
                'application.models.User',
            ),
     ),

),
```

And if you want English Language, then add this to your config/main.php

```
'language' => 'en',
```

then go to index.php/yiiadmin